# If only a Sith deals in absolutes, then does Yoda deal with Luke by using absolutes?

Tags: character, analysis, star-wars

Obi-Wan tells Anakin that

> Only the Sith deal in absolutes.

He uses that as his identification that Anakin had actually turned to the Dark Side. (Anakin's statement of "Either you're with me or against me" )

Then is Yoda making an absolute statement, when seeking to make a deal (getting Luke to try again, work harder, DEALING with living with Luke) with Luke says...

> Do or Do not. There is no try.

Is this confirmation that Yoda is a Sith?

Comment: By that logic, isn't "**only the Sith deal in absolutes**" itself an absolute statement?

Comment: Good question, but if you examine the statement, "Do or do not, there is no try." it doesn't equate to an absolute like Anakin's statement does. With Anakin,it is possible to simultaneously not be with him, and not be against him but he is proclaiming that only those 2 possibilities exist. With Yoda, it's not "absolute" because you can not be doing something and at the same time not doing that same thing, you either are doing it or you are not, there is no in-between.

Comment: @DustinDavis You are making the argument mainly based on the fact that Yoda's statement makes sense. Anakin's does not. BUT THE SUPPOSED TRUTH OF "ONLY THE SITH DEAL IN ABSOLUTES" DOES NOT SAY "only the sith deal in ILLOGICAL absolutes "!! The statement you make saying "there is no in-between" in regards to Yoda's "do or no do" is a confirmation that he is in fact dealing in absolutes!

Answer (score 3):

While this IS a valid philosophical question, what it does is call back into question the Jedi Philosophy and the Jedi's failure of the prequel era, which was not re-addressed until *The Last Jedi*.

One reason the Jedi failed was because they could not live up to their own standards, as even in *The Phantom Menace* we might suppose that the reason Anakin is at first rejected to be trained as Jedi by Yoda, has to do with Yoda's own fears of Anakin's fears and "fear is a path to dark side."

> Yoda : The council is confident in its decision, Obi-Wan.
>
> Mace Windu : The boy has exceptional skills.
>
> Obi-Wan : But he still has much to learn, Master. **His abilities have
>   made him... well arrogant.**
>
> **Yoda : Yes. Yes. A flaw more and more common among Jedi. Too sure of
>   themselves they are. Even the older, more experienced ones.**

With that said, each prequel film showed one seasoned Jedi character "fearing" or not completely trusting Anakin. In *Attack of the Clones*, it is Obi-Wan that is worried about his young Padawan, but Yoda is much more reformed, telling Obi-wan that older Jedi have to watch their hubris and, as he reminds Obi-wan, that the clone army is not a victory, which is true not just because of Palpatine's grand plan, but because the Jedi become soldiers for the Republic, which goes against their purview of being negotiators and "keepers of the peace.".

As Mentioned, *The Last Jedi* is the first film to really touch on the failure of the Jedi in the prequels through plots of Luke paralleling Yoda (TESB), himself (TESB), and Obi-Wan (ROTS,ANH), when he fails Kylo Ren and Kylo Ren repeats similar actions of Anakin Skywalker (ROTS).

The following lines of dialogue are all about this:

*The Past Must Die, Kill it if you have to ---> The Jedi Must End ---> I Will Not Be The Last Jedi.*

Luke realizes from Force Ghost Yoda that failure is a powerful teacher and that he can pass that wisdom onto Rey, but also that he can find his way back to the hope and faith in himself, others, and the Force. It can be found again!

**It's this redeeming quality and a hope to reform that has set the Jedi apart from the Sith.**

In terms of Yoda, one can see him as a bit of a flip-flopper and to be fair, he has lost faith in himself and is very old by the time Luke finds him, but he may have been intentionally confrontational as means **to motivate Luke**.

[image]

But we also can see that the way he pushes Luke again in *The Last Jedi*, with both characters in parallel, that Star Wars is thematically consistent in terms of it never being to late to change for the better! It's why Luke was able to spiritually save Darth Vader, and Vader redeems himself in turn by physically saving his son from the Emperor! This is at the heart of 'The Skywalker Saga' and what separates the light from the dark.

However IMO the sequel trilogy, much like the former EU (Legends) is also paving the path for a Force Philosophy evolution through a new generation with two uniquely juxtaposed characters who start out as neither Jedi or Sith and whom are BOTH operating out fear [of identity], and whose story is about discovering their true identity, as they continue to confront the past.

[image]

Perhaps in the future there may not be Jedi or perhaps the Jedi philosophy might evolve in some way that is less apt at alienating it's own members and/or takes better into account the imperfections of humanity (so to speak).

---

*Just To Add As A Point of Interest*

In the *Doctor Aphra & Star Wars* cross over comic mini-series, *The Screaming Citedal*, there was an ancient offshoot of Jedi called, "Ordu Aspectu" that are presented in two ways:

1. They are an extremely enlightened offshoot that more strictly practiced their beliefs to the point of reaching immortality.
2. They are a cult that stole the mainstream Jedi padawans and sacrificed them in order to attempt to reach immortality.

From the looks of the way the plot in comic plays out, Ordu Aspectu seems like they were this "Sith-like" cult, because if "Eternal Rur" is any consolation, then their version of immprtality (a crystal and a crystallized computer system) comes off like an interactive hologram and is ultimately a fake force ghost...

But it seems that the comic wants to make a point about where the line really is between the Jedi and the Sith (or the light and the dark), contesting their legacy once more.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I sort of answered this already. Would you like me to delete this answer, since it was here second?

Comment: It sounds like Jedi do not always speak logically. They speak in error and make mistakes frequently (much like the humans that created them and their universe). The statement made by Obi-Wan is an illogical and incorrect one(he spoke in error). Please explain why you might feel my statement made in this comment is not correct.

Comment: It sounds like you are agreeing with me but not in a way that insults the Jedi (though you are open to questioning them and their logic(Much like Anakin did before moving to the dark side)(I am also doing this)) but I have no problem with me being looked at that way because I have come to the conclusion that their beliefs are illogical and on a lot of occasions wrong!

Comment: @user55665484375 You attempted to edit and change may answer, before making it a comment, and I felt that my answer did address what you are commenting about, and didn't needed it added. You are free to make your own answer. I am following the tenor of Q which IS about questioning the beliefs of the Jedi and IMO is what the narrative of prequel trilogy challenged and what is starting to be re-addressed in the sequel trilogy just like it was in the former EU, as Luke evolved the Jedi philosophy --saved Mara Jade and stated a family while he created a new Jedi school.

Comment: The reason I am pointing this out is because George Lucas himself seems like a man that has made an attempt to create his own religion (belief set and rules made by a human(that are as illogical and wrong as any human creation is)) as opposed to obeying some other religion with a belief set dictated by God. "Lucas has come to state that his religion is 'Buddhist Methodist'" does that not sound like a guy that picks and chooses his own rules and set of beliefs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101798/discussion-between-darth-locke-and-user55665484375).